# mysql update does not work via php script,though it works through the mysql terminal

Tags: php, mysql

i have a mysql table with a column named approved. In case i use the mysql script 
    update tablename set columnname=1 where id=x
where x is an integer number,everything works. 
The problem is when i try to use this script via PHP,where i have the following script:

```
$id = mysql_escape_string($_GET["id"]);

if(true){
    $update = 'update tablename set approved=1 where id='.$id;
    mysql_query($update);
    echo $update;
    echo '<br />database updated :)';
} else {
    echo 'An error occured';
}
//mysql_close($con);
```

where the update does not work..

it does not seem to me that somewhere i have something wrong,so why this does not work?? Do you have any ideas??

thank you in advance

Comment: Try `mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());` to view any errors.

Comment: you where right,turned out i did not make the connection to the database rightly,this was the problem!! thank you!!

Comment: What `echo $update;` actually prints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
mysql_query($update);
```

try this:

```
$result = mysql_query($update);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

-- you'll see what's wrong with your query.

Answer (score 1):

After enabling the mysql_error() function turned out that i was not making rightly the database connection and this was causing the problem!